# IntelliJ mvn package is behaving differently that command line

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-shade-plugin

In my project when I go to the cmd line and type:

> mvn package

It creates a single fat .jar file in my /target directory.

I am using maven shade plugin.

I want to be able to do this in IntelliJ, so in my run configurations for maven, I set the working directory to the root pom.xml folder, and I added the command line 'mvn package'.

It doesn't produce the same output, it just has:

```
classes
generated-sources
generated-test-sources
test-classes
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: When you issue an mvn command you normally have a console output, what does it say in it?

Comment: good catch, it says `Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact....`

Answer (score 31):

As the error states, you have entered an erroneous lifecycle since you also included the `mvn` command itself. That command will be implicitly called (since this is a maven run configuration).

This is what you've got:

[image]

This gives you something like this as an error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.118s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jun 16 15:47:29 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/120M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

So just remove the `mvn` command and make it look like this:

[image]

Your build will now be correct.